# Check views on Vimeo via API

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I need to hide video embedding or deactivate the video once it reaches 200 views. Is it possible to check the count of views of a video on Vimeo via API? I can't find this information on the API reference...

I'm trying with this call:

http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/283030956.json

that video is hidden on vimeo but embedded in a website. When I call the url it returns `283030956 not found`.

Is it a problem with the video's privacy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the video at https://vimeo.com/283030956 either doesn't exist, or is private. The old Simple API you're using (with the path `/api/v2/video/[video_id].json`) can only access videos public on Vimeo.

([The Simple API is also deprecated.](https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360042975791-Deprecated-APIs-libraries-and-upload-methods))

The video's total play count is returned when getting the video's metadata via the full-fledged core API:

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://api.vimeo.com/videos/[video_id]' \
--header 'Accept: application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer [auth_token]' \
```

Documentation is found here:

https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/videos#get_video
https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/responses/video